# Load local image in React JS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

im unable to Load local image in React JS
this is the file location:

ive tried using

```
<img id="shoe1" src="shoe1.jpg"alt="shoe1"/>
<img id="shoe1" src="./shoe1.jpg"alt="shoe1"/>
```

[image]

and within the folder like this too:

```
<img id="shoe1" src="../img/shoe1.jpg"alt="shoe1"/>
<img id="shoe1" src="./img/shoe1.jpg"alt="shoe1"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing the image on top of the files you want to use them? You should follow this page from the documentation:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

```
import shoe1 from './shoe1.jpg';
```

Comment: but what if the image names are from a database?

Answer (score 0):

```
import imgg from "../img/shoe1.jpg";

<img src={imgg} alt="yourimagecomeshere" />
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

can you move the image to assets folder and do something like this

```
<img id="shoe1" src="../assets/shoe1.jpg"alt="shoe1"/>
```